# Group by id dependent less time at postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have table with structure at postgres db :

```
id | item | name  | time
1  | A    | Shoes | 01
1  | B    | Hat   | 02
2  | C    | Shirt | 01
2  | D    | Glove | 02
```

i need to transfor this table into :

```
prev_item | item | name
A         | B    | Hat
C         | D    | Glove
```

it's based on time, time with less should be `prev_item` for each id

how sql do that ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` & `LAG` window function

```
select * from
(
select row_number()over(partition by id order by time desc) Rn,
       lag(item) over(partition by id order by time) prev_item,*
from yourtable
) A
Where Rn = 1
```

Comment: hai @MotoGP, it's not work...i mean...i need to show `prev_item`

Comment: @ihsansat: `lag()` is a window function: see the Postgres tutorial and manual for more details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html